# What is the difference between Image.resize and Image.thumbnail in Pillow-Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to resize an image in pillow-python, however I have 2 functions of choice to use:

`Image.resize` http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize

**and**

`Image.thumbnail`
http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail

Both definitions point out to resizing the image,  Which one should I be using?

Answer (score 92):

`Image.resize` resizes to the dimensions you specify:

```
Image.resize([256,512],PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS) # resizes to 256x512 exactly
```

`Image.thumbnail` resizes to the largest size that (a) preserves the aspect ratio, (b) does not exceed the original image, and (c) does not exceed the size specified in the arguments of `thumbnail`.

```
Image.thumbnail([256, 512],PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS) # resizes 512x512 to 256x256
```

Furthermore, calling `thumbnail` resizes it in place, whereas `resize` returns the resized image.

Comment: `thumbnail` also does not enlarge the image. So e.g. an image of the size 150x150 will keep this dimension if `Image.thumbnail([512,512],PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)` is called.

Comment: Thanks. "Resizes in place" was the key to my issue. I was converting code to use thumbnail instead of resize and I was getting a null return.

Comment: Also, `thumbnail` preserves the aspect ratio. So applying `thumbnail(100, 200)` to a 512x512 image would change the image size to 100x100.

Comment: @HeinvanDyke thanks for the answer. is there a difference in quality when resizing, i.e., does one introduce artifacts while another doesn't?

Comment: `ANTIALIAS` no longer is a valid resample filter.  Should be removed.  Pillow has reasonable defaults, no not needed.

Answer (score 5):

Two examples for thumbnailing, one taken from [geeksforgeeks:](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-image-thumbnail-method/)

```
# importing Image class from PIL package  
from PIL import Image 
   
# creating a object  
image = Image.open(r"C:\Users\System-Pc\Desktop\python.png") 
MAX_SIZE = (100, 100) 
  
image.thumbnail(MAX_SIZE) 
  
# creating thumbnail 
image.save('pythonthumb.png') 
image.show()
```

The second example relates to Python/Django.
If you do that on a django model.py, you modify the `def save(self,*args, **kwargs)` method - like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)                                                                                                                                                                                              
    image=models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='img_profile')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    def __str__(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        return '{} Profile'.format(self.user.email)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    # Resize the uploaded image                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        img=Image.open(self.image.path)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        if img.height > 100 or img.width >100:                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            Max_size=(100,100)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            img.thumbnail(Max_size)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            img.save(self.image.path)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        else:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            del img
```

In the last example both images remain stored in the file system on your server.