# Tensorflow Dataset, only get the train data resized

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to get the input images of the trainset unlabeled.

When loading the dataset I get an odd dictionary first, but I got rid of it.

What I just can't manage is to resize all images to (200,200,3).

My attempt so far:

```
@tf.function
def pre(img):
    return img["image"]

training_daten = tfds.as_numpy(tfds.load(name="cars196", batch_size = 8, split="train").map(pre))

# I got the pictures now, but they're all of a different shape

def pre2(i):
    img_pil = Image.fromarray(i)
    i = img_pil.thumbnail((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    return np.array(i)

training_daten = [list(map(pre2,i)) for i in training_daten]
```

I'm already 5 hours on this.. Thank you very much!

EDIT:
Output of the first batch of my code is:
`[array(None, dtype=object), array(None, dtype=object), array(None, dtype=object), array(None, dtype=object), array(None, dtype=object), array(None, dtype=object), array(None, dtype=object), array(None, dtype=object)]`

So, something doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.thumbnail` method, you can use `.resize` method, because the `thumbnail` method doesn't shape them all in one shape, but calculates the best size and the size you give serves as upper bound on the size.

```
i = img_pil.resize((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29367990/9134528) answer for difference between them.

Comment: It does work, but isn't there a more efficient way? I mean maybe directly on the tfds dataset?

Comment: @WasserSaeufer There is tf.image.resize if you want to use tf.